# Running *.ktr in Java throws KettleMissingPluginsException - Why?

Tags: java, windows, pentaho, kettle

I created a variety of data transformations (*.ktr files) which run perfectly when started from the Spoon GUI (PDI-CE 5.4.0.1-130; Windows 7).

I try to run them from Java with the following code (close to the example code from the documentation):

```
KettleClientEnvironment.init();
TransMeta metaData = new TransMeta("C:\\examplepath\\test.ktr");

Trans transformation = new Trans(metaData);
transformation.execute(null);
transformation.waitUntilFinished();
...
```

When executed, I get the following exception:

```
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleMissingPluginsException: 
Missing plugins found while loading a transformation

Step : CsvInput
Step : XMLOutput
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.loadXML(TransMeta.java:2882)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2718)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2670)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2647)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2627)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2592)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2555)
    at (caller method in my code)
```

As I am not using any plugins but only native steps (in this example CsvInput, XMLOutput), I do not understand the reason for the thrown Exception. Why is it thrown and how can I fix the code to run?

Am I maybe missing maven dependencies? I use the following repository *http://repository.pentaho.org/content/groups/omni/* and dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
    <artifactId>kettle-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0.1-130</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
    <artifactId>kettle-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0.1-130</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
    <artifactId>kettle-ui-swt</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0.1-130</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
    <artifactId>libformula</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0.1-130</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your answers.

Comment: It seems to me that transformation step classes are meant by "plugins" and that your program is not actually loading all the classes it should be loading. But I don't know, I've never seen anybody use Kettle this way. Why not just run it from a command line?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, lukfi. I am currently thinking: What are the consequences of the steps being plugins? The classes for the steps (e.g. FilterRows, CsvInput etc.) are available in the JARs I included via Maven.

Comment: Regarding the _Why in Java?_ question: The main reason is that I need to react to errors / exceptions with the Java code that runs the transformation.

Comment: i tried with a slightly different repo. and its working for me.. you can check this [blog](https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2014/12/29/maven-dependencies-for-building-pentaho-di-kettle-plugins/)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Rishu. I tried it with the repo + dependencies you mentioned. The error is persisting :/

Comment: I cloned the example application referenced in the blog post Rishu shared. This application is working on my machine. I will now step by step compare the two of them and keep you people in the loop about what I find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I accidentally used KettleClientEnvironment.init() but I should have used KettleEnvironment.init(). Consequently, the environment was not properly initialized which triggered the Exception. Wow. That's a rookie mistake :)

The corrected code, as it can also be found in the Kettle docs and Rishu's example:

```
KettleEnvironment.init();
TransMeta metaData = new TransMeta("C:\\examplepath\\test.ktr");

Trans transformation = new Trans(metaData);
transformation.execute(null);
transformation.waitUntilFinished();
...
```

Thanks lufki and Rishu for the comments and pointers.

Comment: this solution helped me